# Non linear ODE solution by odeint

Tags: python, scipy, differential-equations

I have to solve the following differential equation:

[image]

or

[image]

Without the F_1 term the code is straight forward. But I fail to solve it with the F_1 term included though I know the solution should look like a damped harmonic oscillation.

```
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def harmonic_motion(X,t,k,m,tau):
    x,v=X
    F=-(k/m)*x


    F_1=tau/v*(np.gradient(x,t)**2) # This line doesn't work. 

    dx_dt=v
    dv_dt=F-F_1
    dX_dt=[dx_dt,dv_dt]
    return dX_dt


m=1
k=1
tau=0.1
X0=-3
V0=0

t = np.linspace(0, 15, 250)
sol = odeint(harmonic_motion, [X0,V0], t,args=(k,m,tau))
x=sol[:,0]
v=sol[:,1]

plt.plot(t,x,label='x')
plt.plot(t,v,label='v')
plt.legend()
plt.xlabel('t (s)')
plt.ylabel('x,v (m,m/s)')
plt.show()
```

Comment: I think it would be better to solve for the second derivative x'' by using the quadratic formula--you'll have to decide how to handle the two roots--and then convert that to a system first order equations.  Note: there is a typo in your second version of the equation: the sign of k should be positive.

Comment: I'm curious where such an equation arises?  At first it seems natural to interpret the equation as a mechanical system (i.e. some sort of spring), but it is unusual for the *square* of the acceleration to appear in the equations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct version for a spring with air friction is

```
m*x'' + tau*abs(x')*x' + k*x = 0
```

The first order system for this is

```
def harmonic_motion(X,t,k,m,tau):
    x,v = X
    return  v, -(tau*abs(v)*v + k*x)/m
```

The phase plot of this should now give a nice spiral to the origin.